# Python: How to take only one variable (numeral/integer) to R using numpy2ri?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rpy2

My question is simple, I am trying to transport one data point an integer from python to R. The reason for this is because I want to use R functions in R, create the output then back-transform them to python for plotting.

I have done this with arrays it work fine but not with one point array. Consider the simple example.

This below example work fine

```
  import rpy2.robjects as robjects, pandas as pd, numpy as np
    from rpy2.robjects import r
    from rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri import numpy2ri
    from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

    r_p1= numpy2ri(np.array((1,1)))
```

No problem! However if `r_p1= numpy2ri(np.array((1)))` instead of `r_p1= numpy2ri(np.array((1,1)))`

I receive the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d404ef525bdb> in <module>()
      4 from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
      5 
----> 6 r_p1= numpy2ri(np.array((1)))
      7 
      8 # df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((108, 2)), columns=['Number1','Number2'])

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\numpy2ri.py in numpy2ri(o)
     80         #FIXME: no dimnames ?
     81         #FIXME: optimize what is below needed/possible ? (other ways to create R arrays ?)
---> 82         res = rinterface.baseenv['array'](vec, dim=dim)
     83     # R does not support unsigned types:
     84     elif o.dtype.kind == "u":

RRuntimeError: Error in (function (data = NA, dim = length(data), dimnames = NULL)  : 
  'dims' cannot be of length 0
```

## Edit

Just to ask my question better, as I understood from there is no way one may use one integer rather than an array in R.

But what I really need is to call a function in R that takes in input one of them is a single numeral such as 3, or maybe 21, elements that are determined in python.

In particular, I am calling such a library in R `r('library("vars")')`

Whereby I want to use some matrix call it y 2 by 100

```
# Run a normal VAR model
r("t=VAR(y, p=p1, type='const')")
```

as you may see this p1 is a single number say 3 (which is selected in python)

as `r.assign("p1", r_p1)` d

```
# Then find the summary statistics
r('s=summary(t)')
```

this gives me this error

```
RRuntimeError: Error in crossprod(resids)/obs : non-conformable arrays
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
np.array((1, 1))  # tuple of length 2
np.array((1))     # literally the integer 1
np.array((1,))    # tuple with a single element
```

calling it on the third example `np.array((1,))` worked for me

This is kind of weird, because there’s no such thing as a plain number in R; everything is a vector (sometimes of length 1). As far as I could tell from documentation, this is the best way to send an integer over.

Comment: sometimes simple things make it really hard to figure it out when you are in a big code

Comment: @dgg I edit my question to be more precise I wish you may have a look into it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What I really wanted to do is to transfer one numerical value (which is one entry in a matrix) to R. The reason for this is to use any integer from python onto a function in R that requires an input that has an integer. Unfortunately, this leads to many errors. To come over it requires to take the input as a string variable. This has been done as so

define a string variable that can have a variable single integer in python such as

```
p1= int(5) # variable integer in python
A='t=VAR(y, p='+str(p1)+', type=\'const\')'
```

then one may simply call the function VAR in R as

```
r(A)
```

This will solve the mystery